# mongo query : How can a direct key-value pair be placed from a nested array in a single stage pipeline and without the use of $unwind?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have something like this.

```
{
  "priceDetails": [
    {
      "cities": [
        {
          "cityId": "64a297a8bb1dc440ccef6c3c",
          "name": "Bhopal",
          "prices": "1200",
          "commissionType": "PERCENTAGE",
          "commissionValue": "20",
          "_id": "64a2990b344e735476fb54ca"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Need something like this.

```
{
  "priceDetails": {
    "cityId": "64a297a8bb1dc440ccef6c3c",
    "name": "Bhopal",
    "prices": "1200",
    "commissionType": "PERCENTAGE",
    "commissionValue": "20",
    "_id": "64a2990b344e735476fb54ca",
  }
}
```

I tried $unwind, but it uses a lot of database processing power to filter and retrieve the data.

I'm using node v18.7.0 & mongo version v4.4

I'm baffled at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to get a result like this or to change your db structure like this? Also, Is `cities` always contains only one item?

Comment: If you only want to retrieve the first item you can use `$first`

Comment: yes, i want response in that given form, and also don't want to change structure of db, and "cities" will always contain only one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your present pipeline for aggregating data, you can utilise $set and $arrayElemAt.

To modify the response, use $set, and to retrieve an element from an array, use $arrayElemAt.

```
{
  $set: {
    priceDetails: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {
          $arrayElemAt: ["$priceDetails.cities", 0]
        },
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The first index of the array will be set by inner $arrayElemAt. in the outer array's 0 index. The outer $arrayElemAt will then act in a manner similar to that of the inner $arrayElemAt.

Consult the document for more details.

$set : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#definition

$arrayElemAt : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/

I hope that this may be useful to you or someone else.

Comment: It performed flawlessly for me and satisfied my needs. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a simple projection:

```
db.collection.find(
  {},
  {
    _id: 0,
    priceDetails: {$first: "$priceDetails.cities"}
  }
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2hq0IZr8Qbj)